# Where is the camp store?

Tags: psychonauts

I've been regaled numerous times with talk of all the wonderful things that I can buy at the camp store, but I feel like I've explored pretty much the entire camp now, and I haven't located it.  I've also looked at the map, and haven't seen anything that seems to indicate where it is.  I'm sure its obvious, but where exactly is the store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Camp Store is inside the lodge, which is in the "Main Campgrounds" zone of Whispering Rock:

It's just to the right as you enter the lodge.

Answer (score 4):

The camp store is inside the lodge. Agent Cruller is inside in a chef's hat and apron, and if you talk to him, he will let you know what you can buy. What you can buy depends on your rank - as you reach a higher rank, you will be able to buy more items.

Comment: Ah, I was there, but didn't recognize it as the "store".  Silly me.